# Add connection timeout in ruby code

Tags: ruby

How I can configure connection timeout in this ruby code?

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
request.basic_auth("user", "pass")
```

For example every 1 second I would like to make connection attempt and print the result.

Comment: Set `http.open_timeout` and `http.read_timeout`.

Comment: Can I also set the connection attempts and print the number of each attempt?

Comment: This will simply set the timeout. If you want to make continuous requests one after the other, you have to do so in a loop. In said loop, you can count your attempts.

Comment: Can you show me working example please?

Comment: Try something like `count = 0; loop { response = http.request request; break if count > max_retries || satisfactory?(response); }`.

Comment: @ndn `loop.inject(0) ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scheduler gem such as [Rufus Scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) to schedule your task to run every second.

Install the gem

```
gem install rufus-scheduler
```

Sample code:

```
require "net/http"
require 'uri'
require "openssl"
require "rufus-scheduler"

url = URI("https://google.com")
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.singleton

scheduler.every '1s' do 
    p Net::HTTP::get(url)
end

scheduler.join
```